# mysql installation on SUSE 15 Failing with : Problem: nothing provides 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)'

Tags: mysql, opensuse, suse, sles

Im trying to install mysql on SUSE 15 Sp2 :
Followed steps from official documentation :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-sles-repo-quick-guide/en/
But when i tried to install the mysql getting following error :

> Problem: nothing provides 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)' needed by the
> to be installed mysql-community-server-8.0.29-1.sl15.x86_64
> Solution
> 1: do not install mysql-community-server-8.0.29-1.sl15.x86_64
>
> Solution 2: break mysql-community-server-8.0.29-1.sl15.x86_64 by
> ignoring some of its dependencies

Answer (score 0):

According to the list of [platforms that are supported by this version of MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html), version 15.3 of openSUSE is required. That's probably what's going wrong here: The version of glibc which is provided by the repositories of your openSUSE 15.2 is too old for this MySQL version. If possible, I would recommend you backup your system and then upgrade to 15.3 and then to 15.4, [see these instructions](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:System_upgrade). Especially when you intend to do development, it's *really* wise to first upgrade your OS to the latest version, because only then will you have the latest versions of the technologies you're learning – otherwise, some things you learn will be outdated from day one.